# Excel Formula For Between Start Date and Time and End Date And Time

Tags: excel, date, datetime

I've been tasked with writing, what I thought would be, a simple formula to return `TRUE` or `FALSE`. The formula is looking at a Start Date, End Date, Start Time and End Time and checking against a "Check Date" and "Check Time".

If the "Check Date" and the "Check Time" are within the Start Date, End Date, Start Time and End Time, then the returned value should be `TRUE`

For example:

**Start Date**: 12/01/17

**End Date**: 14/01/17

**Start Time**: 00:30

**End Time**: 18:00

**Date Check**: 13/01/17

**Time Check**: 22:00

**Result** = TRUE

I cant find a formula that will cover every single possible scenario here, am I overthinking it?

**UPDATE**

Here's the formula as requested... It's not pretty

```
=IF(AND(CHECKDATE>STARTDATE,CHECKDATE<ENDDATE),TRUE,IF(AND(CHECKDATE>=STARTDATE,CHECKTIME>=STARTTIME),IF(AND(CHECKDATE<=ENDDATE,CHECKTIME<=ENDTIME),TRUE,IF(CHECKDATE=STARTDATE,IF(CHECKTIME>=STARTTIME,TRUE,FALSE))),IF(CHECKDATE<=ENDDATE,IF(CHECKTIME<=ENDTIME,IF(AND(CHECKDATE>=STARTDATE,IF(CHECKDATE=ENDDATE,CHECKTIME<=ENDTIME,CHECKTIME>=STARTTIME),IF(CHECKDATE=ENDDATE,IF(CHECKTIME<=ENDTIME,TRUE,FALSE))),TRUE,FALSE)))))
```

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing the formula you're using. Kindly update your post to include that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have separate fields for date and time, simply combine them with addition before testing.

```
=AND([Start Date]+[Start Time] <= [Check Date]+[Check Time], [Check Date]+[Check Time] < [End Date]+[End Time])
```

[image: screenshot]

Note that when time is involved, one normally wants to use half-open intervals `start <= time < end` because when we specify an end-time, we mean at that time the event is over (or whatever the range represents).

Comment: Thank you, I was drawing a blank and completely forgot that time is the decimal value and I could just add them together...